# Dynamic html- find what variable causes page to update

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm inspecting a dynamic html webpage. There is an element that looks like this:

```
<span id="x">3</span>
```

It's value constantly changes based on some variable. So for example if the variable changes to 10, the text inside the span element will also change to 10 like this:

```
<span id="x">10</span>
```

I want to find where this variable is that is causing this change. Where in inspect element can I find this variable and manipulate it?

Comment: How do you want to change your value from being `3` to `10`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Try the sources tab of the Dev Tools.

If can't find it in the elements tab, try the sources tab:

[image]

For example this is looking at some JavaScript of github.com:

[image]

Look for the JavaScript that may be manipulating this element, I have no idea what it could be, but I'd first look for something along the lines of:

```js
var [VARIBALE_NAME] = document.getElementById("x")
```

Though on many dynamic web pages it can be very difficult to find something like that. This is because many web pages are dynamically created and tend not to be very human-readable.

Comment: found it in the js file in sources.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to script tags in the inspect page and search where it is getting this element. i.e, somewhere in the script there will be something like this;

```
document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = that-variable-which-you-are-finding; // as the id of the span is x.
```

In this way you will get the name of the variable. Then in the script tags, search for that variable on other positions and you will get where it is getting updated.